# how to animate each character in mathjax equation using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate **mathjax** chemical equation in my html template.The animation should convert one form equation to another form of equation(like converting **co2** to **c2h2** by adjusting space).

for example:   `3c2h2 -----> c6h6` in this equation i want to change **c6h6** to **co2** by **adjusting(squeez)** the space.here co2 will be animated from any part of the page and before it occupies **c6h6** place **c6h6** will be shorten its with to fit for **co2**.I am not able to do it can some one help me on this.

Comment: http://letteringjs.com/

Comment: I want to know this too. I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-dev/E1gw3PTCAaw but I don't quite understand his code.